# Changing the stroke color of map overlay on tap

Tags: ios, swift3, mkmapview

I have a map view and I am generating a bunch of mkcircle overlays. These have a stroke width and fill color.

I also have a tap gesture set up that determines if the tap is on one of the mkcircles. What I would like to do now is change the stroke width and fill color so the user knows which mkcircle was tapped and then change it back on any other tap.

The code I have is below.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
    circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
    circleRenderer.lineWidth = 2
    return circleRenderer
}

func handleMapTap(_ gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapPoint = gestureReconizer.location(in: mapView)
    let tapCoordinate = mapView.convert(tapPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
    let point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(tapCoordinate)
    if mapView.overlays.count > 0 {
        for overlay: MKOverlay in polygonArray {
            if (overlay is MKCircle) {
                let circle = overlay
                let circleRenderer = (mapView.renderer(for: circle) as! MKCircleRenderer)
                let datapoint = circleRenderer.point(for: point)
                circleRenderer.invalidatePath()

                if circleRenderer.path.contains(datapoint) {

                    let circleIndex = polygonArray.index{$0 === circle}!
                    print(circleIndex)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have done some searching but I have not been able to find a solution yet. I am able to get the circleIndex of the tapped circle.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: In handleMapTap, are you not able to change the strokeColor and lineWidth of circleRenderer?

Comment: Yes. I just found that out and was about the answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone else comes across this here is the answer which was actually pretty easy in the end.

```
func handleMapTap(_ gestureReconizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapPoint = gestureReconizer.location(in: mapView)
    let tapCoordinate = mapView.convert(tapPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
    let point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(tapCoordinate)
    if mapView.overlays.count > 0 {
        for overlay: MKOverlay in polygonArray {
            if (overlay is MKCircle) {
                let circle = overlay
                let circleRenderer = (mapView.renderer(for: circle) as! MKCircleRenderer)
                let datapoint = circleRenderer.point(for: point)
                circleRenderer.invalidatePath()

                circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
                circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue

                if circleRenderer.path.contains(datapoint) {

                    circleRenderer.fillColor = UIColor.black
                    circleRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.black
                    let circleIndex = polygonArray.index{$0 === circle}!
                    print(circleIndex)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution.

Comment: How to change last selected polyline colour?